# Blender 2.8 Render Farms

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I've just created an environment to be used in a 360 degree video in Blender 2.8 and was planning on rendering with cycles and using the help of a render farm. I was in contact with one render farm but have since found out that they wont render anything on 2.8 as its still in the beta stage of development. Does anyone know of any render farms that will render stuff from blender 2.8 or alternatively know how to transfer my environment from 2.8 to 2.79?
Cheers!!!

Comment: I think in regards to asking about render farms this will likely be closed as a duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender

Comment: "GPU Oven" supports Blender 2.8 is lead by a single person named 'Mirko Jankovic' as it is a free render farm you can give him your project & give him some money to keep his farm up for every beginner ;) You can contact him personally on his website; https://www.gpuoven.com/

Comment: I am not sure if it still free. It was free when I gave him my project quite long time ago...

Answer (score 2):

We at GarageFarm.NET support Blender 2.8 projects over at the farm. You can download and install our scene preparation plugin from your web dashboard after registering, and enable it on your preferences tab in Blender. It will be listed with "update to 2.8x required" but you will be able to enable it. You can register [here](https://garagefarm.net/blender-render-farm/) and get free $50 worth of credits.

Feel free to reach out to our support team as well! They are available 24/7 via our chat application (hit the chat icon on the page).

We acknowledge that 2.8 is still in BETA, and so there's no guarantee you won't run into problems, but our wranglers will be there to assist you whenever you need them, and we've rendered some 2.8 projects successfully already.

Cheers!

Comment: I think you still have Blender Big Shot;
 https://garagefarm.net/blender-big-shots/ 
Do you still have this offer? (I was amazed seeing a profile of GarageFarm.NET in Blender Stack Exchange Great!)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the offer still stands. You can fill out the form on the website to get in touch with us.

Answer (score 1):

SheepIt renders on 2.80, though it's not necessarily updated often to the latest build. Plus it's free.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked Rebusfarm? https://es.rebusfarm.net/en/3d-software/blender-render-farm I remember using version 2.80 with them and everything went fine, also offer credits for testing which is cool because you don't have to spend any money to test it out... cool render farm, check them out